linux bash shell can node display long texts
I'm experiencing an issue with terminal line wrapping in Bash on Ubuntu where long input text doesn't properly wrap to the next line. Here's the specific behavior:
enter image description here
 130 ❯ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 27; columns 112; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>;
start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc

I tried add some config follow by claude, but none works

create input.rc

❯ cat .input.rc 
set horizontal-scroll-mode off
set wrap-mode on
set bell-style none
#set editing-mode emacs
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
set mark-symlinked-directories on


add config to bashrc

bind 'set disable-completion off'
bind 'set page-completions on'
bind 'set completion-query-items 1000'
bind 'set show-all-if-ambiguous on'
bind 'set show-all-if-unmodified on'
bind 'set mark-symlinked-directories on'
bind 'set visible-stats on'
bind 'set completion-ignore-case on'
bind "set enable-bracketed-paste on"


A couple of steps to troubleshoot: 1) run bash --norc to see if the same behaviour persists. If not 2) start normally bash, and type PS1='$ '  to see if the same behaviour persists

This is usually due to problems with the prompt string (PS1). Remember to use \[...\] to surround escape sequences that don't take up space.

BTW, even though this was closed here (correctly, as the problem is not specific to software development), it's likely to be on-topic on other Stack Exchange sites; consider [unix.se] or [ubuntu.se]
